# Get last two max dates from one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table I'd like to get desired data from.

The table itself looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+------------+-------------------------------+
| persnr | client | date       | other columns with other data |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 123    | 1      | 01.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 1      | 02.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 1      | 03.01.2021 |                               |
| 999    | 1      | 01.01.2021 |                               |
| 999    | 1      | 02.01.2021 |                               |
| 999    | 1      | 03.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 9      | 02.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 9      | 10.01.2021 |                               |
```

I'd like to get the two latest (newest) dates that are not the same, per person and client and would therefore need

```
+--------+--------+------------+-------------------------------+
| persnr | client | date       | other columns with other data |
+--------+--------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 123    | 1      | 02.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 1      | 03.01.2021 |                               |
| 999    | 1      | 02.01.2021 |                               |
| 999    | 1      | 03.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 9      | 02.01.2021 |                               |
| 123    | 9      | 10.01.2021 |                               |
```

a person with the same number but a different client can be seen as an completely different person.

I tried getting getting the latest date first using

```
select distinct persnr, client, max(date) as date
from app_hours
group by persnr, client
```

and for one persnr and client to get the two latest dates I'm using

```
select distinct top 2 date
from app_hours
where persnr = '123' and  client = '1'
order by date
```

I'm struggling with combining them. I'd be thankful for any hints and tips.

Comment: oh, my bad, yes, other columns.

Comment: yes exaclty. two most recent dates which are not the same (sorry, DD-MM-YYYY format here) per persnr and client.

Comment: sorry, english is not my first language and I messed up. edited the post-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a [row number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) using your criteria, and then filter out all but the first 2 rows e.g.

```
with cte as (
    select *
        -- change to date desc for the most recent as your results show
        , row_number() over (partition by persnr, client order by date) RowNumber
    from app_hours
)
select *
from cte
where RowNumber < 3
order by client, persnr, date;
```

Comment: thank you very much. not quite there yet to completely understand your approach but I'm working on it